# Rails: Should I be handling rendering logic in the view or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

My Rails app /index path should show one page to logged in users, an entirely different page to admin users, and a totally different one for users who aren't logged in.

So, one controller (HomeController), one action (index), three views.

I can implement this in two ways:

1. Insert `if` clauses into `views/home/index.html.erb` making it do the right thing.
2. Put the conditional logic into the controller somehow (make the controller find out who the user is) and then render a different layout accordingly, as described under **2.2.12 Finding Layouts** in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.

I have a strong feeling the latter solution is the right one. But I'm not sure how to implement it, what with the user controller being a totally different controller. How can my home controller find out who the current user is to decide what view to render?

Comment: Have a look for the presenter pattern and Ruby On Rails.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I second that.

Comment: I just spent quite a bit of time researching presenters, starting with Jay Fields' original post, all the way to Draper. This seems like total overkill for my app and for my skill level. I'm a clueless noob -- I'm trying to learn  an easy, sensible way to do something like this. If there's no such way, I'd accept that as an answer, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to current_user object in all controllers, to check whether user is logged-in or not. Also we can get user role from the current_user object by

> current_user.role_name

You can pass this role name to render partial as file name(Keep different files).

Comment: I think this is the direction I need. Does role_name come from the rolify  gem?